# preseeding locales in debian

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, preseed, localization

I am trying to use debconf to preseed the values for the `locales` package in Debian squeeze, so that I can reconfigure it non-interactively to, e.g., generate all locales. I extract the right selection from a working system using `debconf-get-selections`, and then feed them to `debconf-set-selections` on the new system.

It is working for other packages, e.g. `sun-java6-bin`, not quite for `locales`. I am able to set the values with `debconf-set-selections`, but if I reconfigure `locales` with `dpkg-reconfigure` (or reinstall it with, e.g., `apt-get install --reinstall locales`, for that matter), the values are reset and the new locales are not generated.

Symptoms are exactly the same as in [debian bug #592216](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=592216), but that bug is officially resolved in version 2.9-13 of the package. Squeeze has 2.11.3-4, so either the bug is still there, or I am doing something wrong.

Has anyone experienced the same thing?

Thanks in advance

-- M

Comment: Bug reported: [#697765](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=697765)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have experienced the same problem, and after fighting it for a while, I found a workaround that uses `/etc/locale.gen`.

I published a puppet module to configure the locales we usually use on our servers, that is, only `en_US.UTF-8`:

https://github.com/cosimo/puppet-modules/blob/master/locales/manifests/init.pp

Here it is, inlined:

```
class locales {

  package { "locales": 
    ensure => "latest",
  }

  file { "/etc/locale.gen":
    source => [
      "puppet:///locales/locale.gen.$fqdn",
      "puppet:///locales/locale.gen"
    ],
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    mode => 644,
    require => Package["locales"],
  }

  exec { "/usr/sbin/locale-gen":
    subscribe => File["/etc/locale.gen"],
    refreshonly => true,
    require => [ Package["locales"], File["/etc/locale.gen"] ]
  }

}
```

Even if you don't use puppet ;-), you can easily understand what's happening. You just create the `/etc/locale.gen` file with the list of locales you want to generate, and then run the `/usr/sbin/locale-gen`.

Here's the list file I use as `/etc/locale.gen`:

```
# This file lists locales that you wish to have built. You can find a list
# of valid supported locales at /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED, and you can add
# user defined locales to /usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED. If you change
# this file, you need to rerun locale-gen.

en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks cosimo, see my answer below (cfengine code included ;)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a cfengine3 policy similar to @cosimo's manifest, and it appears to work. I am fine with that, but I still believe that bug #592216 is not resolved yet so I may file another one to Debian.

My cfengine implementation takes advantage of the fact that `/etc/locale.gen` seems to contain all the possible locales, but commented out.

Rather than rewriting the file from scratch, and possibly introduce errors, I am asking cfengine to uncomment the locales I want to be generated. If the locale is not there, be it because it's not supported or I misspelled it, nothing happens. This approach also simplifies things in that it is not necessary to write both the locale **and** the charset: you can just write the locale and let cfengine uncomment all the related charsets for that locale.

'nuff said:

```
body common control
{
      inputs => { "cfengine_stdlib.cf" } ;
      bundlesequence => {"test"} ;
}

bundle agent test
{
  vars:
      "locales"
    slist => { "da_DK.UTF-8", "de_DE.UTF-8", "en_US.UTF-8",
           "es_ES.UTF-8", "fr_FR.UTF-8", "it_IT.UTF-8",
           "nl_NL.UTF-8", "ru_RU.UTF-8", "sv_SE.UTF-8",
           "tr_TR.UTF-8", "id_ID.UTF-8", "nb_NO.UTF-8",
           "pl_PL.UTF-8", "vi_VN.TCVN"  },
    comment => "locales to generate" ;

  files:
      "/etc/locale.gen"
    edit_line => enable_locales(@(test.locales)),
    classes   => if_repaired("regenerate_locales"),
    comment   => "Enable locales, trigger locale-gen if needed" ;

  commands:
    regenerate_locales::
      "/usr/sbin/locale-gen"
    comment => "Regenerate locales when needed" ;

  reports:
    regenerate_locales::
      "Locales regenerated" ;
}


bundle edit_line enable_locales(locales)
{
  replace_patterns:
      "^#\s+($(locales).*)$"
    replace_with => uncomment ;
}
```